# how put user input into a variable in an SQL statement using c/c++

Tags: c++, c

I'm quite new in all this programming. But I wanted to know how to pass a variable value into an/a SQL/MYSQL statement in a C/C++ query code.

For example, I wanted to select from database: mysql_query(conn, "select * from ;");
Say that  is a variable and receives user's input. How do I actually do that? Any idea will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you show some code about how you are setting up your connection? What library are you using? Also do you want C, or C++? They are different.

Comment: Based on the example in your question, an obvious / easy way is `std::string query("select * from "); query += user_input + ';'; mysql_query(conn, query.c_str());`.  Most SQL APIs also allow you to vary some parts of queries without having to recompile them completely, but that's more troublesome and you might as well start with something simple if you're new to all this.

Comment: Be **very** careful when handling user input to SQL statements.

Answer (score 3):

You could use `std::string` as other said, but you could also use [`sql::PreparedStatement`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connector-cpp-examples-prepared-statements.html) which are a lot more safe :

```
sql::Connection *con;
sql::PreparedStatement *prep_stmt
const char* tableName = "foo";

prep_stmt = con->prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM ?");
prep_stmt->setString(1, tableName);
prep_stmt->execute();
```

When using [prepared statement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement), the DBMS will parse and compile the statement *as is* and will bind the values of the parameters only at the execution of the statement. This allow you to reuse the same statement multiple times with different parameters but also offer you a strong protection against [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sql_injection) since you let the DBMS take care of the parameters.

Answer (score 2):

To make milleniumbug's warning more explicit: Google "SQL injection". The solution is prepared statements.

`std::string sql = "select * from ?;"`. This is a statement which you can prepare and then execute. When preparing, MySQL finds the `?`, and when executing you just need to provide a value for `?`. MySQL will then insert the table name for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `std::string` to easily build an SQL statement.

```
#include <string>

std::string CreateSelectStatement(const std::string& tableName)
{
    std::string  sql;

    sql = "select * from " + tableName + ";";

    return sql;
}
```

You can then use the string to query the database.

```
std::string sql(CreateSelectStatement("sometable"));

mysql_query(conn, sql.c_str());
```